# Java restful service response filtering

Tags: java, json, filtering

Using: RestEasy+Spring boot+Java

Have plenty of endpoints created over a period of time which emits large payload json. From the client perspective (again java) how can I effectively filter the responses just by specifying the attributes of interest. i.e. It should be very generic.

Tried squiggly-for-java but its not working/not very generic

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to code it yourself, and are looking for a library to do it. Sorry, but [questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Graphql is the way to go in spring boot to solve the issue. Refer link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what's GraphQL was created for.

Have a look here: https://graphql.org/learn/

It's also available for Java https://graphql.org/code/#java